# Disprove: $f\circ g = f \circ h \implies g=h$ for a surjective function $f$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, function-and-relation-composition

I tried using a very specific counterexample here where I select a surjective function for which the compositions are equal but the functions within are not.

This is probably off-base, but it's what I've got so far.

---

Assume $f \circ g = f \circ h$.

Consider the surjective function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = x*sin(x)$.

> Should I prove this is surjective before proceeding?

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $g \neq h$ given by

$g(x) = 0$ and $h(x) = 2\pi$.

> Can I choose these constant functions? Do I need to define domains and codomains?

$(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x)) = f(0) = 0 * sin(0) = 0$

$(f \circ h)(x) = f(h(x)) = f(2\pi) = 2\pi * sin(2\pi) = 0$

Observe that $f \circ g = f \circ h$ $\land$ $x_1 \neq x_2$.

Thus we have given a counterexample to disprove the statement. Thus surjectivity of $f$ is not a sufficient condition for the statement to be true.

---

I understand the proof completely now and understand I have it correct, thank you for your responses.

Comment: Hint:  let $f$ be surjective but not injective.  Now look for constants $g\neq h$.

Comment: ... Is my function $f$ injective? I thought it wasn't. I guess I should prove that the function is strictly surjective.

Comment: Ah, I misread it.  Yes, your function works perfectly.

Comment: To generalize a little bit: take any surjective even function $f$ (yours is a good example), and take  $g=-h$ (where $g$ is not the zero function).

Comment: If $g=-h$, there's no guarantee $f \circ g = f \circ h$ for a general surjection.

Comment: There is the word "even." @M10687

Comment: Sorry, misread that.

Comment: A common instinct of students is to pick examples like this from calculus. But, with practice, it is just as easy to make examples with finite sets. Let $g(0) = 1$, $g(0) = 1$, $h(0) = 0$, $h(1) = 0$, and $f(0) = f(1) = 0$. Then $f \circ g = f \circ h$, where the domain is the finite set $\{0,1\}$ and the codomain of $f$ is $\{0\}$.

Comment: Also, for any $f, g, h$, once you have $f \circ g = f \circ h$ you can just cut down the codomain of $f$ to make it surjective. You should make sure that you can name the domain and codomain of your functions, but whether your instructor requires you to write them out is something we can't answer.

Comment: Also, a small comment regarding the current answers: this looks rather clear from the OP's post and the  tags, but the current answers do not address whether the given proof is correct (which is the very point). Instead, they give alternative solutions... @J.S.R., consider making what you ask (proof verification) more explicit?

Comment: I guess the last time I wrote this very proof for credit, I lost 2/3 of possible points just because I didn't define the domain and codomain. I was wondering if there was a bigger problem at play here that made it wrong. That being said, the feedback has given me some good ideas. I will say though that functions defined over intervals tend to confuse me more than those in infinite sets like $\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R}$, etc, maybe this is unusual, haha.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [-1,1]$, $f(x)=\sin(x)$. Then let $g(x)=x$, $h(x)=x+2 \pi$. $f$ is surjective and $f \circ h= f \circ g$, but we clearly don't have $h=g$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f:X\to\{0\}$ where $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in X$. Then, you can specify $g:X\to X$, $h: X\to X$, and $X$ as you like; *any* such choice (with $|X|\geq 2$) will work.

Comment: To get $g \not = h$ we'll need $X$ to have at least two points. +1

Comment: @CarlMummert Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be the set of students of  a class. Let $g(s)$ and $h(s)$ denote the scores obtained by student $s$ in Geography and History respectively.
Thus $g,h$ are functions from $S$ to $[0,100]$. Let $f\colon[0,100]\to \{A,B,C,D,E,F\}$ be a function that assigns letter grades to numerical scores.

Now I leave it to you work out a scenario where each student gets the same grade in both the subjects, that is, $f\circ g = f\circ h$. Does that necessarily mean the scores are same in both the subjects for each student?